# Jar file Works different on Mac and Linux

Tags: java, swing, jar, paint

Hey i made an java Projekt which runs very good on Mac see screenshot 1.
But when i run same project on linux it seems to give some troubles may someone has an idea why this happens? it seems repaint does not work correctly on linux.

```
private void startGame(){
        gameOver = false;
        loop = new Timer(10, new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent x) {

board.play();
frame.repaint();
 }});
 loop.start()}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {

    Point a = board.getBird().getLeftBottemCorner();
    Point b = (board.getBird().getRightUpCorner());
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.fillRect(a.x, a.y, b.x - a.x, b.y - a.y);
    drawHurdles(g);
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.drawString("Score: " + board.getBird().getHighScore(),10 , board.getBoardHight()+15);


}
    private void drawHurdles(Graphics g) {
g.setColor(Color.black);
ArrayList<Model.BOX> hurdles = board.getHindernisse().getHurdles();
Iterator<BOX> it = hurdles.iterator();
Point a;
Point b;
BOX akt;
int hoehe;
while (it.hasNext()) {
akt = it.next();
hoehe = akt.getRightUpCorner().y - akt.getLeftBottemCorner().y;
a = akt.getLeftBottemCorner();
b = akt.getRightUpCorner();
g.fillRect(a.x, a.y, b.x - a.x,  hoehe);
 System.out.println(a + ", " + b + ", " + hoehe);

}
}
```

Maybe someone have an Idea why repaint do not clean on linux?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please provide the piece of code that behaves odd.

Comment: Code please. Nobody can help you like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `super.paint(g);` in your `paint` method, to get rid of the paint artifacts. But you shouldn't even be painting on JFrame. Instead paint on JPanel and override `paintComponent` and call `super.paintComponent`. See examples and best practices at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)

Comment: thanks i already painted at a jPane. super.paint(g) has solved the Problem.

Answer (score -1):

You could try to dispose of graphics.

```
public void paint (Graphics g) {

       g.setColor (Color.white);
       g.fillRect (0,0,2000,1000);
       // your painting stuff here
       g.dispose();
}
```

Comment: -1, you should never dispose of the Graphics object passed to a painting method. You should only dispose of Graphics objects the you create in your code. Also, custom painting should override paintComponent() not paint() and you should invoke super.paintComponent() to clear the component background before doing the custom painting.

Comment: @camickr IIRC, whether you override `paint()` or `paintComponent()` depends on whether you are using AWT or Swing.

Comment: @camickr It is good to override paint method of JPanel, which is the most often way games are done in Swing. Call of super is unnecessary.

Comment: When i would it like this it will overpainting all directly.

Comment: @Pils19 Mixed it. Paint your sprites after painting white rectangle. But that is not really a solution because I have suspicions you will eventually run into some sort of memory leaks. Post full code.

Comment: When i paint first white rectangle it does not work :( - same error on linux

Comment: @DavidConrad, Correct, but the question is tagged "Swing" and the posted code is using a "Swing Timer". Anyway the main point is about disposing the Graphics object, it should never be done.

Comment: @camickr Oops, good point. My mistake.

Comment: @Pils19 do NOT override JFrame paint related methods (which i guess you are since it is called frame). Instead extend JPanel and override its methods. JFrame does not have doublebuffering etc which will lead you in other problems later even if you solve this one.